# Is getPixel and setPixel available for Images in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk, getpixel

I am trying to understand if it is possible to access (read / write) single pixels within an image in Corona. Looking at http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html and surrounding documents seems its not available, but I would appreciate a short confirmation from a Corona expert.

*(some tags to make it searchable in the future: getpixel, setpixel, bitmap, corona)*

Answer (score 1):

Since Daily Build 2106 you can get the color of a pixel in the display:

[Color Sample Function](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/30/introducing-the-color-sample-function/)

And for setpixel you can place a new rect of 1×1.

[newRect Function](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newRect.html)

Answer (score 0):

In one word: no :)

I think Corona is going to implement this in the future, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Its not there, here is the place users can vote for that feature on corona website http://feedback.coronalabs.com/forums/188732-corona-sdk-feature-requests-feedback/suggestions/3625203-bitmap-manipulation-read-pixel-e-g-for-selecti